# Electron: require is crashing program

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

In my electron renderer, I have the following script:

```
<script>require('main.js')</script>
```

In that file, everything is commented out and my program keeps crashing. If I change the above to:

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

The file loads, however I cannot use require within that file. What do I need to change to get this to start working?

### Edit:

I think the issue might be because I am using pug to generate my html like so:

```
block content
  script.
    require('../../js/client/main')
```

When I use an actual HTML file, it loads without hanging.

Comment: Are you getting any sort of error in the console?

Comment: Nope, It starts up, attempts to load the Developer Tools (but just displays as a white window). Sits for about 5 seconds then closes.

Comment: Sometimes, anything running chrome (spotify, vscode, chrome, slack) they all crash too

Comment: Try doing `require('./main.js')`. I'm pretty sure require doesn't work with a absolute resolution path for non-node-modules.

Comment: I have tried `require('../../js/client/main')` and `require('C:/path/to/app/js/client/main')` both produce the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it looks like the issue was that electron was trying to load a `.js.map` file from the wrong location. `electron-pug` was intercepting the url of the file and since it was not found it was throwing an error (not handling it very well it seems).

My solution to fix this was to have inline sourcemaps instead of having a separate file.